# Load two different Json dat in Odd and Even rows - ngGrid- AngularJs

Tags: json, angularjs

I am trying to load two different json data for even rows and odd rows like what we see **[here](http://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html)**. I did try multiple sources as a refernce using **ng-grid**, but none has any solution. Kindly tell me the possibility on the same. Is it possible to do the same.

**HTML**

```
<div class="list-view-body">
   <div class="list-view" ng-grid="settings"></div>
</div>
```

**AngularJS**

```
$scope.settings = {
    data: 'records',
    enableColumnResize: false,
    enablePaging: true,
    enableRowSelection: false,
    rowHeight: 35,
    headerRowHeight: 35,
    totalServerItems: 'totalServerItems',
    pagingOptions: {
        pageSizes: [15, 20, 50, 80, 100],
        pageSize:15,
        currentPage: 0
    },
    showFooter: true,
    footerRowHeight: 0,
    columnDefs: [
        {field: 'id', displayName: '', width: 25, cellTemplate: '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="lv-show-tasks" ng-click="show_campaign_tasks($event);"><span class="caret-right"></span></a>' },
        {field: 'reports', displayName: 'Reports', width: 75 },
        {field: 'opportunityName', displayName: 'Opportunity', width: 250},
        {field: 'proposalId', displayName: 'Proposal ID', width: 95},
        {field: 'startDate', displayName: 'Start date', width: 90},
        {field: 'endDate', displayName: 'End date', width: 90},
        {field: 'amount', displayName: 'Amount', cellTemplate: '<div class="ngCellText"><span>{{row.entity.amount | currency:\'USD$\'}}</span></div>' },
        {field: 'alertss', displayName: 'Alerts'},
        {field: 'healths', displayName: 'Health'},
        {field: 'commentss', displayName: 'Comments' },
        {field: 'flag', displayName: 'Flag', cellTemplate: '<div class="ngCellText"><span class="action-icon lv-flag true"></span></div>' }
    ]
};
```

Comment: Do you want `show_campaign_tasks()` to show details underneath the current row?

Comment: Yes, thats what I require.. @gidomanders

Answer (score 1):

I think it would reach to mix the two data json sources in the controller, intercalate them and displaying the result using a ng-grid directive ... something like this

```
// main.js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.myOddData = [{name: "Moroni Odd", age: 50},
                 {name: "Tiancum Odd", age: 40},
                 {name: "Jacob Odd", age: 20},
                 {name: "Nephi Odd", age: 30},
                 {name: "Enos Odd", age: 34}];

$scope.myEvenData =   [{name: "Moroni Even", age: 51},
                 {name: "Tiancum Even", age: 43},
                 {name: "Jacob Even", age: 27},
                 {name: "Nephi Even", age: 23},
                 {name: "Enos Even", age: 34}]; 

 $scope.result = $scope.myOddData.reduce(function(arr, v, i) {
                          return arr.concat(v, $scope.myEvenData[i]); 
                       }, []);                
$scope.gridOptions = { data: 'result' };
```

});

Here the related Plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/MyV5pBXK4rQEmbfbCjgL